# Energy density of gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravitational-waves

If the mass is small enough, we can approximate to the GEM (gravitoelectromagentism). In this apporximation, we can calculate the energy density of gravitational field, such as $u_g=-\frac{g^2}{8\pi G}$ for field generated by mass that is at rest. As you see, the energy density of gravitational field can be negative, but is it also possible for a gravitational waves? Maybe it is impossible, but I can't figure it out why. Can somebody help me?

edit: if two identical gravitational waves with opposite direction moves toward each other and creates a standing wave, is there some moment $t=t_0$ that only gravitational fields are detected, and no gravitational torsion? If that moment exists, does the energy of wave can be negative? If it doesn't, why?